# USN-6154-1: Vim vulnerabilities fix for non-pro Ubuntu 18.04 version

Tags: 18.04, security

There is a new vulnerability reported for vim which I'm not able to rectify as apparently it requires pro version of Ubuntu in order to download the upgrade:

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6154-1

I'm not a Linux guy and from time to time I need to support some of our Ubuntu EC2 instances. That said, Is there a solution to apply this patch without having a pro subscription at all? What are my options?

Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: The obvious answer to this is to backport the fix yourself & compile. The benefit of Pro is just that that job is done for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 is no longer supported here. We won't answer questions about how to patch it. Sorry.

Your organization has three options:

1. Spin up new instances running newer releases of Ubuntu for free support.
2. Paid support.
3. Hiring a "Linux Person" to manually support your old instances.

There's no real secret to patching, it's just a learned skill and dozens of online tutorials are available. But it's not something I would do on a five-year-old production server that is no longer supported. Too much risk for too little reward.

Advice: Invest your organization's resources in spinning up a 22.04 instance, and start testing migration paths.

EDIT: 18.04 is the title. Folks running supported releases of Ubuntu will discover that these patched packages will be installed by Unattended Upgrades automatically. Since the packages are in Main, everybody gets the patches (Pro is irrelevant).